# How to disable (or hide) the close (x) button on a JFrame?

Tags: java, windows, swing

I have a window (derived from JFrame) and I want to disable the close button during certain operations which are not interruptible.  I know I can make the button not do anything (or call a handler in a WindowListener) by calling

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

but I would like to make it clear visually that it is pointless to click it.

Comment: Just a suggestion, you might want to consider avoiding such GUI behavior due to poor usability.

Comment: I agree with Josh. At the very least map close to a popup that says "Operation in Progress..." with a "Cancel" (hides popup) and "Close Anyway" (forces quit) button. When the background operation completes the app closes if that popup is still visible (i.e. they haven't clicked Cancel)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide the default minimize/maximize and close buttons on JFrame window in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101418/how-to-hide-the-default-minimize-maximize-and-close-buttons-on-jframe-window-in)

Comment: What about Frame, instead of JFrame?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, [this bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6199687) indicates that this is currently not possible.

Answer (score 24):

This is probably the best you are going to get:

```
setUndecorated(true);
getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.NONE);
```

This will remove the entire titlebar, java doesn't really specify a way to remove individual components of the titlebar

edit:

There may be a way, check out these threads:

- [link 1](http://saloon.javaranch.com/cgi-bin/ubb/ultimatebb.cgi?ubb=get_topic&f=2&t=015407)
- [link 2](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?messageID=10255068)

Answer (score 8):

This will help you:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(0);
```

Comment: Why the hell was this downvoted without any comment? It blocks the close operation as requested. Although better expressed as `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE)`

Comment: I had to use those three lines to avoid java shutting down when I have several PApplet (Processing) launched: `this.jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE;
this.jframe.setUndecorated(true);
this.jframe.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.NONE);`

Comment: As Tomas Zato said, It helped me ;)

Comment: Downvoted because the original question specifically said, "I know I can make the button not do anything....by calling setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE) but I would like to make it clear visually that it is pointless to click it."

Answer (score 5):

For those coming to this later than 2008, there has been a change making it possible to do this. See [this link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/344419/GUI/java/deactivate-close-minimise-resizable-window)

Second response from the bottom shows how to do it by name.

Comment: Like many other things in Swing, this too is a complete PITA.

Comment: *Second response from the bottom*, which one is it now, 5 years later? Can link to it ("share" link at the bottom of it) or quote the core principle?
Also, could you detail a bit more the "change" you're referring to?

Answer (score 0):

To simply make them disappear, try the following:

```
setUndecorated(true);
```

Comment: This unfortunately removes the title and the window cannot be moved or resized.

Answer (score -2):

Please try this

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        e.getWindow().setVisible(false);
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(WindowsActions.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
      }
    });
```

Comment: This not only has nothing to do with the question, but it's not even sound logic. This is a horrible thing to do in the code. NEVER do this.