# How to hide the default minimize/maximize and close buttons on JFrame window in Java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I would like to know if it is possible to create a `JFrame` window which has no default maximize/minimize(-) and close(x) buttons! I have added custom buttons on each frame so that the user does not have to mess around with the default ones on the top right corner of the window!

Comment: Of course, now he'll have to mess with your custom buttons with subtle usability bugs.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [JWindow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JWindow.html) because is by default un_decorated, but you can [setUndecorated()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated%28boolean%29) for JFrame/JDialog

another ways are

- implements [WindowListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html)
- [setDefaultCloseOperations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29)

Comment: How do you do that with setUndecorated() fro JFrame/JDialog! Can you give an example ?

Comment: `setDefaultCloseOperations()` won't hide the buttons, it just changes the behaviour of the application when the window is closed.

Comment: hmmm I posted link to API, then there isn't required any adds example

Comment: @Xris It's a method that takes one boolean parameter, there's not exactly a lot ways to use it.

Comment: Also, `setUndecorated()` will make the entire window title bar and border disappear. This means you'll have to reimplement window moving and resizing as well.

Comment: @Inerdial that could be little bit complicated, by default is better use un_decorated JFrame (can be used parent) as JDialog/JWindow, in the case that you required second/another popup window then JWindow is best at all

Comment: @mKorbel Any undecorated window, will require a custom implementation of the entire title bar. Doesn't matter whether a `JWindow` or a `JFrame` with the flag set to true. (A `JFrame` would indeed be better as the root window because of `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`.)

Comment: @Inerdial agreed witout any comment(s)

Answer (score 5):

Use [JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated%28boolean%29). It may not be the exact thing you need but doc  says,

> Provides a hint as to whether or not newly created JFrames should have
>   their Window decorations (such as borders, widgets to close the
>   window, title...) provided by the current look and feel.

Try this code:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(100, 100);
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.NONE);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

This will remove the entire titlebar. Also take a look at this [thread](http://www.coderanch.com/t/344419/GUI/java/deactivate-close-minimise-resizable-window).

Otherwise use [JWindows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JWindow.html).

Comment: The title bar  on the window is totally gone so the side effect is user can't move the window by dragging on the title bar or resize the window.

Answer (score 0):

```
JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

Will make the 'X' button no functioning. It's works for me.

Comment: Not what was asked for.

Comment: Only option works for me.  I have my own close button and menu to close down app and in there additional logic will need to be checked before close the app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Netbean then just unselect the resizable option in properties.
It will only disable Minimize/Maximize Button.

Answer (score 0):

```
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.NONE);
```

Comment: A little bit of commentary around the code would be nice, but good answer to the question.

Comment: Setting window decoration style seems unnecessarily. See docs:

public void setWindowDecorationStyle(int windowDecorationStyle)

Sets the type of Window decorations (such as borders, widgets for closing a Window, title ...) the JRootPane should provide. The default is to provide no Window decorations (NONE).