# Hide buttons on title bar in Java

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

In Jinternal Frame(java), i want to hide max, min, close button (not disable max, min, close properties), but when I used this code :

```
javax.swing.plaf.InternalFrameUI ifu= jif.getUI(); //jif : finternalframe//
((javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI)ifu).setNorthPane(null);
```

It made all the buttons and the title bar disappeared (imagine the internalframe is a retangle, so only 3sides(down, left and right) visible).

So, how could I hide only 3buttons max, min and close without hiding all the title bar?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> ..want to hide max, min, close button

[image: RemoveControls]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class RemoveControls {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
                p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,120));

                JDesktopPane dtp = new JDesktopPane();
                p.add(dtp);

                JInternalFrame jif = new JInternalFrame("JIF",
                    false, //resizable
                    false, //closable
                    false, //maximizable
                    false); //iconifiable
                jif.setVisible(true);
                jif.setSize(200,100);
                dtp.add(jif);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See this...
http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/swing/minimize-maximize.shtml

Close Button Problem....

[How to disable (or hide) the close (x) button on a JFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276254/how-to-disable-or-hide-the-close-x-button-on-a-jframe)

Comment: Thanks but i also want to hide close button, i alredy edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using netbeans, its easy. Simply create a new JInternalFrameForm by right clicking on any of your package.

Simply add this JInternalFrameForm to any of you container (say a desktop pane for example).

My JInternalFrameForm name is internal1 and my desktop pane name is desk.

// pseudo code :

```
    InternalFrame mboxFrame = new internal1();
    mboxFrame.setResizable(false);
    mboxFrame.setSize(desk.getWidth(), desk.getHeight());
    mboxFrame.setLocation(0, 0);
    mboxFrame.setVisible(true);
    desk.add(mboxFrame);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot hide these buttons. I tried this as well and was not successful. However, there is a work around for this, which was to create a custom title bar. It is sorta tedious but it works.

The following steps should help you:

1) invoke the `setUndecorated(true)` method. This will, unfortunately, remove the title bar completely but will allow you to do step 2.

2) Then, create a class that will allow you to make a title bar using `JFrame`. Keep in mind that the window buttons appear on the right-hand side for Windows OS and on the left for Mac OS. The title text is also centered on Mac and left aligned on Windows.

3) Use `JLabel` to display your title text and `JButton` to display the, minimize, maximize, and close buttons.
I would also recommend grouping the buttons and positioning the title text to make title bar look similar to the one that the OS on your computer displays

4) [Optional] you can attach an `ActionListener` to the buttons to render the window behavior. This includes `setState()` for minimizing and `setExtendedState` for maximizing. Closing a window gives you two options `System.exit(0)` for applications and `dispose()` for applets

5) [Also optional] to disable the buttons, simply use the `setEnabled(false)` method. In your case, to hide these buttons, you would use `setVisible(false)`

The following code snippet demonstrates this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class TitleBar extends JPanel
{
    private JLabel titleLabel; //create this to hold the title text

    JFrame frame    = new JFrame();

    int pX, pY; //used for window dragging

    private JButton closeBtn, minBtn, maxBtn; //create these for the window buttons

    public TitleBar(String title)
    {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 28));

        titleLabel = new JLabel(title);
        titleLabel.setOpaque(true);

        JPanel controls = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 0, 0)); //define this to hold the title text and window buttons

        closeBtn    = new JButton(); //define the Close button
        closeBtn.setBorderPainted(false);

        //set the icons for the states
        closeBtn.setIcon(new WindowButtonIcon().new CloseIcon(true, false));
        closeBtn.setPressedIcon(new WindowButtonIcon().new CloseIcon(true, true));
        closeBtn.setDisabledIcon(new WindowButtonIcon().new CloseIcon(false, false));

        //Apply the more fine adjustments
        closeBtn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(17, 17));
        closeBtn.setRolloverEnabled(false);
        closeBtn.setFocusPainted(false);

        //Attach this action listener to render the "close window" function
        closeBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        minBtn      = new JButton(); // define the Minimize button
        minBtn.setBorderPainted(false);

        //set the icons for the selection states
        minBtn.setIcon(new WindowButtonIcon().new MinimizeIcon(true, false));
        minBtn.setPressedIcon(new WindowButtonIcon().new MinimizeIcon(true, true));
        minBtn.setDisabledIcon(new WindowButtonIcon().new MinimizeIcon(false, false));

        //Apply the more fine adjustments
        minBtn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(17, 17));
        minBtn.setRolloverEnabled(false);
        minBtn.setFocusPainted(false);

        maxBtn      = new JButton(); //define the Maximize button
        maxBtn.setBorderPainted(false);

        //set the icons for the selection states
        maxBtn.setIcon(new WindowButtonIcon().new MaximizeIcon(true, false));
        maxBtn.setPressedIcon(new WindowButtonIcon().new MaximizeIcon(true, true));
        maxBtn.setDisabledIcon(new WindowButtonIcon().new MaximizeIcon(false, false));

        //Apply the more fine adjustments
        maxBtn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(17, 17));
        maxBtn.setRolloverEnabled(false);
        maxBtn.setFocusPainted(false);

        //This JPanel will set up the title text and window buttons
        controls.setBackground(null);
        controls.add(minBtn);
        controls.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(4, 0)));
        controls.add(maxBtn);
        controls.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(4, 0)));
        controls.add(closeBtn);

        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 0, 3));

        //construct the custom title bar
        add(titleLabel);
        add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(790, 0)));
        add(controls);

        //These render window dragging
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me)
            {
                // Get x,y and store them
                pX = me.getX();
                pY = me.getY();
            }

            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me)
            {
                frame.setLocation(frame.getLocation().x + me.getX() - pX, frame.getLocation().y + me.getY() - pY);
            }
        });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter()
        {
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me)
            {
                frame.setLocation(frame.getLocation().x + me.getX() - pX, frame.getLocation().y + me.getY() - pY);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This class constructs the title bar in the Windows appearance. Note that the `Icon` class that was used used here is not given, however, you can create a class that can display one.

The `MouseEvent` listeners are a must if you want window dragging.

The `ActionEvent` listener for the close button is also a requirement if you wish to close the window. Hiding and disabling this button will naturally disable this feature

I hope this helps.