# Make an In-game window

Tags: java, swing, window, jlabel, jdialog

How would I make an In-game window?

So to put this simply, I'm making a game. the window for the game is not full screen, it is only 1000 by 800 pixels. for this game, i am making a blueprint class for in-game windows, so that i can have a window for inventories, stores, main menu, pretty much anything you can think of. So, I've tried using `JDialogs`, but they are separate windows, and I kind of want it to be painted to the main panel... kind of like a `JLabel`, but as a window. I've been doing a lot of google searches, and tried a lot of different things, such as the aforementioned dialog, and label, but I'm just not sure how to do this. All I need is an in-game window/menu. does anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Additinal info: if anyone has played Guild Wars 2, or World of Warcraft, you know what i'm talking about. Think about the separate inventory windows, and store windows, etc.

**EDIT:** I tried what the comments suggested, and here's how I initialized the new panel:

```
setSize(w, h);
setLayout(null);
setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

And I add this panel using `mainFrame.add(new GameMenu());` and nothing happens. When I make the frame, in the `main` method, I do it this way:

```
f = new Frame();
core.setFrame(f);
f.add(new GameMenu());
f.add(new Panel()); //panel is the main game panel
f.setVisible(true);
```

And it shows up and works just fine. So what is different about this, and why is my first way not working and the second work?

Comment: just add another `jpanel`

Comment: interesting idea, but how would i make the panel disappear behind the borders of the frame, not obviously take up the whole frame...?

Comment: what do you mean *disappear behind the borders of the frame*? panels must be added to `jFrames` in order to be displayed and they are limited to the `jFrame` size, but they don't have to be the same size as the frame, it can be set using `setSize()` (altho I don't recommend you do so as it should be handled by using [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)).

Comment: ahh alright ill try that and see how it goes

Comment: If you want different panels to stack up, just use the [cards layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: Perhaps you are after a `JDesktopPane` with `JInternalFrame` instances to hold the panels.  E.G. as seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9365450/418556).

Comment: `Frame` has it's own layout manager (`BorderLayout`), which means only one component can occupy a given position (like `CENTER`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! all i had to do was just make a smaller JPanel (cause i didnt know that you could make it do that XD) and have it do what i want! Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

[`JInternalFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html) might be what you are looking for. An internal frame is normally added to a `JDesktopPane` but it also works if you don't want that overhead. The Java Tutorial has a good [introduction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html).