# How to disable close button in JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable (or hide) the close (x) button on a JFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276254/how-to-disable-or-hide-the-close-x-button-on-a-jframe)

I want the frame to have a deactivated close button, but I don't want to do `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE )`;
nor `frame.setUndecorated(true)`.

I want the frame to appear but the close button should look inactive/disabled.

If we cant achieve this in `JFrame` is there a way to do this? You suggestions will be of great help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best answer is that it is not possible.

I would choose the `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE` and override the windowClosing event in its WindowAdapter as the best option.

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    // do whatever else
  }
});
```

Comment: Is there any other Java GUi which allows this capability. I see applications like skype disables the close button on their log in window. How do they achieve that, Any idea.

Answer (score 3):

This [bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6199687) says that it is not possible , though it is a old link but it is not probably added in jdk yet :(

Comment: +1 for digging up the bug :-)

Comment: Thats not cool, wondering if that is possible with any other java gui.